# Is it illegal to serve baby seafood in Italy?

Tags: legal, italy, food-and-drink, genoa

It should, but what does the law say?

In Greece for example, it is illegal to serve baby seafood of many species, following the over-fishing in the Mediterranean.

So, *is it illegal in Italy to serve baby seafood*?

[image]

Comment: It's called purpetielli affogati in Italy, braised baby octopus, very popular in Campania (and elsewhere).

Comment: @Giorgio I didn't see why it is popular. If I eat in a traditional taverna, then I will probably see the reason, thanks.

Comment: It may not be your choice (or mine, for that matter :D)... There was a time, years ago, that I declined the sheep brains and eyes in Greece, despite being the guest of honor.

Comment: @Giorgio I give you that, never tried them, and hopefully never will. Although it seems that this custom decays as modern times approach..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Travel.

Comment: Baby octopus seems to be a popular delicacy all around the world...

Comment: super cute baby octopus hatching https://twitter.com/VAAquarium/status/961230569525907456

Comment: Strange... I read that as feeding seafood to human babies, and then wondered why anyone would imagine that being illegal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not illegal.

Octopus are not subject to EU quotas and there is no minimum landing size. https://www.mcsuk.org/goodfishguide/search?name=Octopus,%20Lesser

It is not unusual in Italy to eat baby octopus.

Comment: Great link, I will probably use it in the future, thanks.

Comment: Besides, some species are farmed, so they wouldn't be subject to wild-caught regulation. (not octopus AFAIK)